# How to take two images and show with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

This is what I tried, but images are not show on the screen, why?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var camera = false
    @State private var holeTop: UIImage?
    @State private var holeBottom: UIImage?
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .overlay {
                                holeTop != nil ? Image(uiImage: holeTop!).resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white) :
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                selectedImage = holeTop
                                camera = true
                            }.padding(24)
                        Text("Hole top")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .overlay {
                                holeTop != nil ? Image(uiImage: holeBottom!).resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white) :
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                selectedImage = holeBottom
                                camera = true
                            }.padding(24)
                        Text("Hole bottom")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $camera) {
            CameraView(selectedImage: $selectedImage)
        }
    }
}

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var isPresented
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.sourceType = .camera
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(picker: self)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
    var picker: CameraView
    
    init(picker: CameraView) {
        self.picker = picker
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        self.picker.selectedImage = selectedImage
        self.picker.isPresented.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI I was working on adding to the other answer when you unchecked it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735498/why-taken-photo-is-not-visible-with-swiftui/74735521?noredirect=1#comment131915181_74735521

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `selectedImage` is not assigned to `holeTop` or `holeBottom`.  You are assigning the value of `holeTop` to `selectedImage` not a reference.

Here is one way it could be done. Define an `action` to happen upon camera dismissal and then perform that `action` with `onDismiss`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var camera = false
    @State private var holeTop: UIImage?
    @State private var holeBottom: UIImage?
    @State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @State private var action: ()->() = { }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Form {
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .overlay {
                                holeTop != nil ? Image(uiImage: holeTop!).resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white) :
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                action = {
                                    holeTop = selectedImage
                                }
                                camera = true
                            }.padding(24)
                        Text("Hole top")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Circle()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                            .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                            .overlay {
                                holeBottom != nil ? Image(uiImage: holeBottom!).resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white) :
                                Image(systemName: "camera")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 24, height: 24)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }.onTapGesture {
                                action = {
                                    holeBottom = selectedImage
                                }
                                camera = true
                            }.padding(24)
                        Text("Hole bottom")
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    }
                } header: {
                    Text("")
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $camera, onDismiss: action) {
            CameraView(selectedImage: $selectedImage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw, you had this copy/paste error `holeTop != nil ? Image(uiImage: holeBottom!).resizable()` where you clearly meant `holeBottom` instead of `holeTop`.  I fixed that in my answer.

Comment: Any feedback on this answer? Did it work for you?